# A complex formula that can spot matching cells and compare them

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So what i have is,

Column A contains a set of 400 names

Column B contains a set of %s

Column D contains 1000 names, all 400 from A are in this column but in a random order

Column E contains a set of %s

In column C, I want a formula that can check column A for the matching cell in column D, then, I need it to compare the relative % in column B and Column E. I need it to return true or false if the percentages for the correct names appear.

I am only checking column A against D so the missing 600 names are not included.

I have NO idea where to even begin with this...

Here is what I hope this will look like:

[image]

Comment: You need much more detail here.  Provide a tiny sample input and what you would expect as an output.  Also, "I need it to return true or false if the percentages for the correct names appear" needs to be clarified.  What are you doing with these percentages?

Comment: I will add a picture of how this will look. and the true and false relates to VLOOKUP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I jimmied up some sample data.  Here you go (though you should be more clear and offer sample data, as @Choirbean suggests)...

The solution is in both columns C and D, since you ambiguously posed two questions.

In C2, you would have:

```
    =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,E:E,1,FALSE)),FALSE,TRUE)
```

In D2, you would have:

```
    =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,E:F,2,FALSE),"n/a")
```

Copy those down, and you get...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

VLOOKUP() is where you would start.

In C1:

```
=B1=VLOOKUP(A1,D:E,2,FALSE)
```

This will return TRUE or FALSE depending on whether the percentages are equal.

Be careful with this as the percentages shown may not be the exact number.  `.0976587` would show `10%` and not equal `.1`

Also this is looking for an ***EXACT*** match on the names.  If there is an extra space or the names are spelled differently it will return `#N/A` because it cannot find a match.

[image]

Comment: The names are computer generated from a program. Both sets of names are exact by the original entry in the 3rd party program. Also, the percentages are rounded to exact percentages with no decimal by the program that should eliminate the percentage errors.

Comment: @jallington one cannot be too sure when dealing with names and percentages.  Also, future traffic may not have the same stringent detail to their data.